# Remote controlled lights

Tags: wires, remote-control

I have a fixed roof light in my room that came with a remote control that can be fully taken apart. The remote control can switch the lights on or off using a radio system. I was wondering if there was any way to use my Arduino to control the remote control (through wires) to control the lights. I do not have any Arduino radio components so it would still need to go through the original remote. I have taken the remote apart and this is what it looks like:

http://go.hma-uk.org/dlt

The buttons are as follows: the top two (K1 & K2) buttons is to turn on/off a coloured LED but these are not important to me. The button K3 is to turn on/off the main light (I want the effect of this button being pressed to be created using the Arduino) and the button K4 is to turn all lights on/off.

Comment: Picture = 404. Attach the picture to the post using the picture button.

Comment: I have 10 pictures, link works for me

Comment: Well, not for me, and probably not for the rest of the world.

Comment: Ill see what I can do

Comment: Works better.  What voltage does the remote run from?

Comment: I don't know the voltage.

Comment: It will tell you on the battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to use gamepads as input device for USB many years ago. I simply soldered wires paralel to buttons and shortcut them to "simulate" the button press - it worked nice and reliable.

With Arduino - I would measure the voltage on the button in question with Voltmeter - if the voltage is less then Vcc of Arduino (5Volts), I would simply connect Arduino ground to lower side (negative) of the button and output pin to the high side of the button. Then I would set that pin for Input to have the button released (from Arduino side) and to LOW + Output to have it pressed. (maybe I would first shortcut the button with Ampermeter to see, that no more, than 100mA is sinking there).

If the sink is more, or the voltage is more, then I would use relay and shortcut the button with the relay, switching the relay with Arduino.

( something like this http://www.instructables.com/id/Home-Automation-How-to-Add-Relays-to-Arduino/?ALLSTEPS )